# Parameter from .ps1 to .psm1

Tags: powershell, parameters

In the powershell scripts, I can give parameters from one script to another by using the $parameter variable and add the following to the top of the script: param([hashtable]$parameters = @{})

One of my files does not have the ending .ps1, it ends with .psm1. Can you tell me why this is another format and what i need to do to get the parameters working like in the other scripts?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103211/when-to-choose-developpment-of-a-powershell-module-over-powershell-script

Comment: Thanks, that explains the module, but not why i can't use the $parameters?!