# What is the purpose of the *.psm1 files in a Powershell module?

Tags: powershell, module

So I implemented my first Powershell module with a bunch of `.ps1` files (one per function) and the `.psd1` manifest file.

I am trying to understand what is the purpose of the `.psm1` files - do I need them at all in my module?

What is their added value?

**EDIT 1**

Here is my `.psd1` file:

```
@{
    ModuleVersion = "0.0.19106.59054"
    GUID = "59bc8fa6-b480-4226-9bcc-ec243102f3cc"
    Author = "..."
    CompanyName = "..."
    Copyright = "..."
    Description = "..."
    ScriptsToProcess = "vsts\config.ps1"
    VariablesToExport = @(
        "TfsInstanceUrl",
        "TfsApiVersion",
        "QANuGetRepoUrl"
    )
    NestedModules = @(
        "db\Backup-Database.ps1",
        ...
        "vsts\work\Get-WorkItems.ps1"
    )
    FunctionsToExport = @(
        "Assert-ExtractionDestFolder",
        ...
        "Write-HostIfNotVerbose"
    )
    PrivateData = @{
        PSData = @{
            ExternalModuleDependencies = "SqlServer"
        }
    }
}
```

Like I said, each function is in its own file.

Comment: Hi, perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103211/when-to-choose-development-of-a-powershell-module-over-powershell-script

Comment: Which tag of `.psd1` file you use to list your `.ps1` files?

Comment: `NestedModules` - see **EDIT 1**

Comment: Although PowerShell allows importing `.ps1` files as modules, them does not create modules the same way as `.psm1` files does. Them does not have their own session state and run in the scope of parent module instead.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the way I created my module without the `.psm1` files? What do I lose in functionality? What do I gain if I rename my `.ps1` files to `.psm1`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> what is the purpose of the `.psm1` files - do I need them at all in my module?

- In *script modules*, i.e., modules authored *in PowerShell* (as opposed to compiled binary cmdlets), **it is only `*.psm1` files that provide the module-specific behaviors distinct from regular `*.ps1` script files** (separate, isolated scope, private commands, control over exported commands).

  - Typically, a script module manifest has a `RootModule` entry pointing to (the main) `*.psm1` file; for smaller modules it is not uncommon for *all* of the module's functionality to be implemented in this one `*.psm1` file.

    - In fact, a *stand-alone* `*.psm1` file can also act as a module, though it doesn't integrate with PowerShell's module auto-discovery and auto-loading feature.
    - Note that if you were to use a regular `*.ps1` script directly in `RootModule`, its definitions would be loaded into the *caller's* scope, not the module's; that is, you would lose the benefits of a module.
- **Even though you're listing regular `*.ps1` scripts in your `NestedModules` manifest entry, by virtue of using that specific entry these scripts are dot-sourced in the *module*'s context and thereby *become part of the module***:

  - This is conceptually equivalent to creating and referencing a root `*.psm1` script in `RootModule`, and - instead of defining a `NestedModules` entry - explicitly dot-sourcing your `*.ps1` scripts from *there* - see bottom section.
  - Note that if you were to reference `*.psm1` files in `NestedModules`, they would truly become *nested modules*, with their own scopes; a nested module is usable from the enclosing module, but not visible to the outside world (though you can *list* it among the loaded modules with `Get-Module -All`).

---

#### Listing `*.ps1` files in `NesteModules` vs. dot-sourcing them from the `RootModule`

While there should be no difference in functionality, using a `*.psm1` `RootModule` to dot-source the `*.ps1` files containing your module's functions can potentially simplify things, *if* you simply need to dot-source *all* `*.ps1` files located in your module directory's subtree:

```
# Add this to the *.psm1 file specified in 'RootModule'

# Find all *.ps1 files in the module's subtree and dot-source them
foreach ($script in 
  (Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -LiteralPath $PSScriptRoot -Filter *.ps1)
) { 
  . $script 
}
```

If you need to load the scripts in a specific order, need only a subset of the scripts, or want to speed things up slightly (though I doubt that the speed difference will be noticeable), you can dot-source the files individually from a `RootModule` `*.psm1` file, as an alternative to listing them in the `NestedModules` entry:

```
# Add this to the *.psm1 file specified in 'RootModule'

# Dot-source the *.ps1 files individually.
. "$PSScriptRoot/db/Backup-Database.ps1"
# ...
. "$PSScriptRoot/vsts/work/Get-WorkItems.ps1"
```

Again, all of the above approaches are functionally equivalent.
Given that you explicitly export functions via the `ExportedFunctions` entry (as is advisable), the use of `*.ps1` files that must be dot-sourced is ultimately an implementation detail that is not relevant for the purposes of command discovery and module auto-loading - it only matters at actual import time.

Answer (score 2):

.psm1 file is powershellmodule file. When we create script module we write all the functions of a module in a .psm1 file then we export the functions and then we can use those functions by importing module.
.psm1 is basically refers the powershellmodule. Powershell directly identifies anything which is written in this file will be a part of module.