# Running a psm1 PowerShell script in Command Prompt (cmd.exe)?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I know nothing of PowerShell, but I wanted to install this: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/lolcat/

So, I start PowerShell as administrator, and:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Install-Module -Name lolcat                                                                                                                                                                                             NuGet provider is required to continue
PowerShellGet requires NuGet provider version '2.8.5.201' or newer to interact with NuGet-based repositories. The NuGet
 provider must be available in 'C:\Program Files\PackageManagement\ProviderAssemblies' or
'C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\PackageManagement\ProviderAssemblies'. You can also install the NuGet provider by running
'Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force'. Do you want PowerShellGet to install and import
 the NuGet provider now?
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): y

Untrusted repository
You are installing the modules from an untrusted repository. If you trust this repository, change its
InstallationPolicy value by running the Set-PSRepository cmdlet. Are you sure you want to install the modules from
'PSGallery'?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "N"): y
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> lolcat

Usage: lolcat [OPTION]... [FILE1[, FILE2[, ...]]]
...
```

Nice, it works. So first I find where is the newly installed script:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> (Get-Module lolcat).Path
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\lolcat\1.0.7\lolcat.psm1
```

Ok, so now I want to try calling this from cmd.exe:

```
C:\Users>PowerShell.exe -File "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\lolcat\1.0.7\lolcat.psm1"
Processing -File 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\lolcat\1.0.7\lolcat.psm1' failed because the file does not have a '.ps1' extension. Specify a valid Windows PowerShell script file name, and then try again.
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6
```

Nope, does not work.

Is it possible to call this PowerShell script from cmd.exe - and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to the fact that the `-File` parameter from the [powershell.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1#-file----filepath-args) excepts a `.ps1` file.

If you want to run `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\lolcat\1.0.7\lolcat.psm1` from cmd, make a `.ps1` script where you can write something like

```
Import-Module lolcat

# now you have all the functions from the lolcat module loaded into this PowerShell session

# do stuff
```

And then call this script from cmd.

The difference between `.ps1` and `.psm1` is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103211/when-to-choose-development-of-a-powershell-module-over-powershell-script).

Answer (score 0):

Eh, turned out to be less complicated then I thought - since it is a "module", just use the module name:

```
C:\Users>PowerShell.exe lolcat

Usage: lolcat [OPTION]... [FILE1[, FILE2[, ...]]]

...
```

Comment: You don't actually run a module file.  When you install a module and import it into your powershell session functions are loaded which you can call from any location.  If you do `Get-Command -Module lolcat` you will see what these functions are.  One of these functions is called `lolcat`, however there are 2 others.  Out-Rainbow is one of them.  Use at the end of any pipeline for some colorful output.  `dir | Out-Rainbow`